# Any way to elide type arguments in TypeScript when irrelevant?

Tags: typescript

I have a function like so:

```
function progress<T>(data: JsonApiQueryData<T>): number {
  const { links, meta } = data.getMeta();
  if (!links.next) {
    return 1;
  }

  const url = new URL(links.next);
  return parseInt(url.searchParams.get('page[offset]')) / meta.total;
}
```

where `JsonApiQueryData` is defined as:

```
export declare class JsonApiQueryData<T> {
    protected jsonApiModels: Array<T>;
    protected metaData: any;
    constructor(jsonApiModels: Array<T>, metaData?: any);
    getModels(): T[];
    getMeta(): any;
}
```

As you can see from the body of `progress`, I am not doing anything to or with the underlying `T` type, so I would *love* to be able to remove the type argument from it.

Naively attempting this, like so:

```
function progress(data: JsonApiQueryData): number {
  ...
}
```

gives me an unfortunate but not surprising error:

```
Generic type 'JsonApiQueryData<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

#### Update

I should have clarified when initially asking, but the `JsonApiQueryData` is a library type that I am unable to change (easily). From the (prompt and pretty great) responses I've seen so far, the best way to achieve *exactly* what I want involves changing that type (to something like `class JsonApiQueryData<T = any>` or `class JsonApiQueryData<T = unknown>`). Sorry for my inadvertent goalpost moving.

Comment: `JsonApiQueryData<unknown>`? Or make it optional with `<T = any>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your type as follows:

```
export declare class JsonApiQueryData<T = unknown>
```

and then you can define your function `progress` without any type annotations.
Note that it will mean something slightly different, namely

```
function progress(data: JsonApiQueryData<unknown>): number {
```

instead of

```
function progress<T>(data: JsonApiQueryData<T>): number {
```

but that should work fine in your case.

Comment: As I can't change the declared type, the equivalent form listed here (`function progress(data: JsonApiQueryData<unknown>): number`) strikes me as the best compromise (well, `function progress(data: JsonApiQueryData<any>): number` due to the ancient version of Typescript in this project).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an interface instead.

```
// interface declaration
export interface HasMetaData
{
    getMeta(): any;
}

// implment interface
export declare class JsonApiQueryData<T> implements HasMetaData {
    protected jsonApiModels: Array<T>;
    protected metaData: any;
    constructor(jsonApiModels: Array<T>, metaData?: any);
    getModels(): T[];
    getMeta(): any;
}
```

Usage :

```
// no need of any generic type
function progress(data: HasMetaData): number {
  // accessing getMeta through HasMetaData
  const { links, meta } = data.getMeta();
  if (!links.next) {
    return 1;
  }

  const url = new URL(links.next);
  return parseInt(uri.searchParams.get('page[offset]')) / meta.total;
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice way to separate the concerns inside the `JsonApiQueryData` type, but unfortunately that's a library class in my scenario, so I won't be able to make any changes to it ✌

Comment: What about create a wrapper class (which implements the interface) around this llibrary class ? @msbit